# Difference between abstract class BaseVMActivity<VM : ViewModel, B : ViewBinding> and abstract class BaseVMActivity(VM : ViewModel, B : ViewBinding)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, binding, android-viewmodel

I'm new to Kotlin and learning it. I came up with some advance syntax.

```
abstract class BaseVMActivity(VM:ViewModel,B:ViewBinding) => This is I know as constructor.
```

But

```
abstract class BaseVMActivity<VM : ViewModel , B : ViewBinding> => This syntax I didn't understand.
```

How it is different from constructor?

Comment: Read about generics in the Kotlin documentation and if that doesn’t make sense read about it in the official Java documentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax with `<>` is for generic type parameters, it is independent from the constructor. You could technically have both at the same time:

```kotlin
class BaseVMActivity<VM : ViewModel , B : ViewBinding>(vm: VM, b: B)
```

You can read a little about generics [in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), but the doc is more focused on the differences with Java (for instance regarding generic variance), rather than explaining the basics of generics. The [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), as mentioned by @Tenfour04, is more instructive.

Basically, generic classes are useful when the code of the class should be identical apart from the types of some input/output values of the class (constructor/method arguments and return types). It allows to have more type safety than just using `Any` everywhere, or another parent type.

For instance, this `Box` class can contain any type of value:

```kotlin
class Box(var value: Any)
```

But when you get an instance of `Box` you can't know what it contains at compile time: accessing `box.value` gives you a value of type `Any`, and you need to cast it (risking failures at runtime) in order to get a usable value:

```kotlin
val box: Box = Box("some string")

val value1: String = box.value // not allowed

val value2: String = box.value as String // risky if box is declared somewhere else

val value3: Int = box.value as Int // compiles fine, fails at runtime
```

Generics are a nice way to add compile-time safety. This is how to declare a generic `Box<T>` class, where `T` is a type that is decided when instantiating the class. `T` is said to be a *type parameter* of the `Box` class. Different instances of `Box` can use a different type for `T` (they can have a different type of value):

```kotlin
class Box<T>(var value: T)


val box: Box<String> = Box("some string")

// this compiles and is safe, because it's a Box<String>, not any box
val value: String = box.value

val value: Int = box.value // doesn't compile
val value: Int = box.value as Int // doesn't compile, because String can't be cast to Int
```

Now this `Box<T>` can be used with any type `T`, but sometimes you want to [constrain that type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-constraints) to only accept some types. This is where the syntax with `:` comes from:

```kotlin
abstract class Animal
class Dog : Animal()
class Cat : Animal()

class Box<T : Animal>(val animal: T)
```

If I declare `Box` this way, only subtypes of `Animal` will be allowed:

```kotlin
val catBox: Box<Cat> = Box(Cat())
val dogBox: Box<Dog> = Box(Dog())
val stringBox: Box<String> = Box("some string") // doesn't compile
```

You can also declare multiple type parameters in a generic class by separating them with commas:

```kotlin
interface Map<K, V>
```

Each type parameter can have its own bounds as well, which is what leads to the syntax you've seen:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseVMActivity<VM : ViewModel , B : ViewBinding>
```

In this case, there are 2 type parameters, `VM` and `B`, which must respectively be subtypes of `ViewModel` and `ViewBinding`.

Comment: Thanks @Joffery That was brief and clear explanation.